# Secured Software Update from an unauthenticated entity

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, updates

Let's suppose we have a software update **D**, that is encrypted and signed and delivered to some component **C**. Further we suppose that the receiving entity **C** can validate the signature and decrypt the software successfully.

I asking myself whether the sending entity needs to authenticate itself to **C**, e.g. by means an authenticated Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange to create a secure Channel and to authenticate the sending entity against component **C**.

As the software update is already encrypted and its origin can be verified, I am asking myself whether the sending entity needs to authenticate themselves. Are there any security issues, when sending secured software over an insecure channel?

Answer (score 1):

> As the software update is already encrypted and its origin can be verified, I am asking myself whether the sending entity needs to authenticate themselves. Are there any security issues, when sending secured software over an insecure channel?

This is largely how Linux distributions such as OpenSUSE, Debian, Ubuntu and others distribute their software. Individual pieces of software is signed by a gpg key, which is trusted by the operating system.

The download is not authenticated or secured; any MiTM is generally free to modify data as they see fit. However, doing so breaks the signature - and the update will not be installed. On Debian, size, md5sum and sha256sum is verified. If all match, package will be installed.

One possible attack here is delaying updates. As previous content tables are signed, they are valid, so a MiTM attacker can reply that 'sorry, no updates for you', and the client will be none the wiser that there may actually be important updates.

A fix for this is to make the client give alarm is no new content appears for a set period. For projects such as Ubuntu, Debian or OpenSUSE, it's rare to go many days without updates, so this would be a solid hint that something is up.

So in short; as long as you use a suitable signature, this distribution model is secure. You don't need to trust the entity that sends you the update; at worst they can send you a broken update, which will not be trusted.